# R apply factor objects

Tags: r

I would like to `apply` the `factor` function over each row of an `R` dataframe.  So, I'd like to get a array of `factor` type objects.  However, when I:

```
apply(df, 1, factor)
```

I don't get that thing.  What am I misunderstanding about `apply` or `factor`?

data:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(flip..1. = c("heads", "heads"), flip..2. = c("tails", "heads"), flip..3. = c("heads", "tails"), flip..4. = c("tails", "tails"), flip..5. = c("heads", "tails"), flip..6. = c("tails", "heads"), flip..7. = c("heads", "heads"), flip..8. = c("heads", "tails"), flip..9. = c("tails", "tails"), flip..10. = c("heads", "heads")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

code:

```
rowwise_factors <- apply(df, 1, factor)
# rowwise_factors seems to be a matrix of characters, or some such, not an array of factor objects.
```

expected_output:

```
dput(expected)

list(structure(c(flip..1. = 1L, flip..2. = 2L, flip..3. = 1L, flip..4. = 2L, flip..5. = 1L, flip..6. = 2L, flip..7. = 1L, flip..8. = 1L, flip..9. = 2L, flip..10. = 1L), .Label = c("heads", "tails"), class = "factor"), 
structure(c(flip..1. = 1L, flip..2. = 1L, flip..3. = 2L, 
flip..4. = 2L, flip..5. = 2L, flip..6. = 1L, flip..7. = 1L, 
flip..8. = 2L, flip..9. = 2L, flip..10. = 1L), .Label = c("heads", "tails"), class = "factor"))
```

What am I misunderstanding here, and also how do I make this work?

W.R.T. CLOSE: these don't answer my question, as I would like to apply this ROW-WISE, not COLUMN-WISE.  Simply transposing my data.frame doesn't make the cited solutions work.

Comment: If your `data` there is a vector, then don't use `apply`. I can't really tell from this sample "data".

Comment: Regardless, even if it is a frame, then `apply(data, MARGIN=1, ...)` is the wrong margin, I cannot see doing this row-wise as meaningful or valid since frames are stored with columnar consistency, not row-wise.

Comment: @r2evans I would like to do this row-wise, yes.  My frame has both column-wise and row-wise consistency.

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually working with (what's the text in that code block?) or what you're trying to get exactly. I'm not really getting how rows would form factors

Comment: Sure, but in a frame, data is stored and consistent column-wise. That is, values in a column must be the same class, but different columns can have different classes. To assign `factor` across each row would suggest that the levels for one value in a column could be different from another row in the same column, which is not how R does things with frames. I suggest you explain why you think this is useful, otherwise short of list-columns (which are likely overly-complicated and certainly difficult for many functions to use), this is not going to happen.

Comment: @r2evans "not going to happen" you mean to imply that this is impossible to accomplish in `R`?  I find that doubtful.... perhaps you mean to say that the solution is complicated.

Comment: @camille the text in the code block is a csv file

Comment: (1) R stores each column as a vector, and all columns are effectively in a named list. (2) In R, a *vector* of factors can have only one set of possible `levels=`. (3) Your premise is that by doing this row-wise, in column `$A` (for instance), row 2 might have one set of levels, and row 3 might have another set of levels. If `$A` really is a vector of factors, then this is an error. *It cannot happen.* (4) If you want to do things this way, your only way forward (I believe) is to use list-columns, which will likely break much of the "normal" frame processing you want to do.

Comment: Okay, so you read that in and get a data frame, and all values are either "heads" or "tails". Are you trying to then make all the columns factors with all the levels unified, i.e. every column is a factor but even if "heads" doesn't occur in that column, it's one of the column's possible levels? Beyond that, like @r2evans already said, data frames do assignment by column, not row

Comment: @camille I would like to get a factor object with "head", "tail" levels, one for each row.

Comment: Do you need individual levels by row? Can you have one set of levels that is the same across all columns? *Why must this be a row-wise operation?* Ultimately, I wonder if what you need is not what we are hearing. Please tell us what you need to be able to do in the end. Perhaps you are thinking row-wise but it can be "transposed" (figuratively or literally) do work with the data in a different method.

Comment: None of that requires factors. What makes you think that you need to use `factor` on your data before considering your contingency table?

Comment: Because I'd like to specify the levels

Comment: I think you're just missing the `simplify` argument - i.e. you don't want the result to be coerced to a matrix, so do `apply(df, 1, factor, levels = c("heads", "tails"), simplify = FALSE)`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento this still doesn't give me a list of factors -- it seems to be applying `factor` element-wise and not row-wise

Comment: w.r.t downvotes, do you have suggestions on how to improve this question?  Is something unclear?

Comment: @Him - not sure what you mean, using your example data it absolutely does return a list (of length 2) of factors, albeit with ugly names attached (which can be removed if desired).

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something ... a contingency table (i.e., return value from `table` or `xtabs`) is just an array with strings as dimension labels. So you want to convert each *row* of a `data.frame` to a `factor` so that, when you compute a contingency table, those `factor`s can then be auto-converted back into a string (with no ambiguity) and the integers in the array as expected? Your factors are lost when calculating tables. Trying to force making them does not make sense to me.

Comment: Your question is not reproducible, I suggest you edit this with: (1) unambiguous data (before any row-wise operations), preferably using `dput(.)`; and (2) a literal R object of your expected output given that sample data (again, `dput(.)` please). I'm not intending to be pedantic or argumentative, but there are some things in R that are "easy" in other languages but not in R. It's unclear why you think you need `factor`s to get to what you say you need.

Comment: @r2evans - agree that it's not clear what OP is trying to accomplish, however, using table on a factor means that you'll get a zero count for missing levels, which won't happen using a character vector.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, sure, but that is not the only unambiguous way to do that. Good point, though, thanks. For example, `table(c("head", "tails", vector_of_headstails)) - 1` will return accurate counts, including 0s.

Comment: For your question about downvotes and whether it's unclear: there are currently more than a dozen comments asking you to clarify this, including workable data and desired output. You could improve it by adding those things to the question

Comment: @Him, I see now how you've structured your input data, so per my "reproducible" comment above, please provide an object of your expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @RitchieSacramento this *does* work.  Apparently, the `simplify` option to apply is recent, and I was a fraction of a version behind.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento if you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @camille the desired output is an array of `factor` objects.  Since these are an internal-R type thing, I'm not sure how to provide additional context to this.

Comment: @r2evans sorry for the delay.  I've added expected `dput` output.  There is a Catch-22 there: It's hard to `dput`  an object when your question involves how to create said object.  :)

Comment: I understand the catch-22, but there are two parts to that: (1) manually build the `list`/`data.frame` with actual names/columns; and (2) have at least a few of the values in the structure be accurate based on the sample data. Most often this is driven by whatever will be using that output.

Comment: BTW, in this case, an acceptable "expected output" could have been: `list(factor(c("flip..1"="heads","flip..2"="heads",...)), factor(...), factor(...))` or similar. Perhaps I should have made that more clear. Just like mathematical proofs sometimes benefit from going from the solution towards the original problem, it can help here to know what type of ultimate transformations are needed. Good luck, Him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in R-4.1 and newer, as that is when `simplify=` was added to `apply(.)`:

```r
apply(df, 1, factor, levels = c("heads", "tails"), simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
#  flip..1.  flip..2.  flip..3.  flip..4.  flip..5.  flip..6.  flip..7.  flip..8.  flip..9. flip..10. 
#     heads     tails     heads     tails     heads     tails     heads     heads     tails     heads 
# Levels: heads tails
# [[2]]
#  flip..1.  flip..2.  flip..3.  flip..4.  flip..5.  flip..6.  flip..7.  flip..8.  flip..9. flip..10. 
#     heads     heads     tails     tails     tails     heads     heads     tails     tails     heads 
# Levels: heads tails
```

This works in R before 4.1:

```r
lapply(asplit(df, 1), factor, levels = c("heads", "tails"))
# [[1]]
#  flip..1.  flip..2.  flip..3.  flip..4.  flip..5.  flip..6.  flip..7.  flip..8.  flip..9. flip..10. 
#     heads     tails     heads     tails     heads     tails     heads     heads     tails     heads 
# Levels: heads tails
# [[2]]
#  flip..1.  flip..2.  flip..3.  flip..4.  flip..5.  flip..6.  flip..7.  flip..8.  flip..9. flip..10. 
#     heads     heads     tails     tails     tails     heads     heads     tails     tails     heads 
# Levels: heads tails
```